# A isometric map in metric space is surjective?

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36502/isometries-of-mathbbrn)

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f$ be an isometric map from $X$ to $X$. Prove $f$ is a surjective map.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74326 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36502/.  (These were found with the Google search `site:math.stackexchange.com isometric compact surjective metric`.)

Comment: In particular, [Qiaochu's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36511/9754) answers this as well.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the proof linked to in the comments:

Suppose there existed $x \in X\setminus f(X)$. Then $x$ has positive distance $d$ from the compact set $f(X)$. Now consider the recursively defined sequence $$x_0 := x, \qquad x_n := f(x_{n-1}) \quad \forall \, n>0$$ 
We have $d(x_0, x_n)\ge d$ for all $n>0$, by assumption on $x$. This implies that we also have $d(x_k, x_{k+n}) = d(x_0, x_n) \ge d$ for all $k,n>0$ (here we use that $f$ is an isometry). Therefore $d(x_n, x_m) \ge d$ for all $m\ne n$, which is in contradiction to sequential compactness of $X$.

Comment: Interesting argument!