# Isometry in a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

From the answer of the question [isometry $f:X\to X$ is onto if $X$ is compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189490/isometry-fx-to-x-is-onto-if-x-is-compact) , I found out that the answer is valid only if the range of the sequence $\{x_n:n \in\mathbb N\}$ is infinite.

Now I'd like to know if the range is finite. Then $x_{n+k}=x_n$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$, so the sequence is periodic. By intuition, I guess the isometry $f$ satisfies $f^k=id.$, but I have no idea to prove this. I only know that the isometry is injective. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: Why is the answer valid only when the sequence's range is infinite? I suppose it would be better if the answer said "cluster point" or "accumulation point," rather than "limit point," but it seems like it works fine with that adjustment. Am I missing something?

Comment: The three terms has the same meaning, and the Bolzano-Weierstrass property states that every "infinite" subset of a compact space has an accumulation point. If the range of sequence is finite, then the finite number of points cannot have accumulation point.

Comment: The terms have the same meaning for *sets*, but for *sequences*, "limit point" implies uniqueness, while the other two do not. For example, the sequence $n\mapsto (-1)^n$ has *no* limit point. However, both $-1$ and $1$ are cluster/accumulation points for the sequence.

Comment: Then your argument in the previous question is under assumption that $x$ is 'limit point' of the sequence, so I guess the argument should be changed by 'accumulation point' or 'cluster point' argument.

Comment: I read your answer again, and I found that just changing 'limit point' to 'accumulation point' makes your answer valid even if the range is finite. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You're very welcome! (P.S.: It isn't my answer. I just edited a typo while I was looking at it. ;-))