# Travel of the point via isometry: does it get closer to home?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $f\colon X\to X$ — isometry. We fix an arbitrary point $x\in X$ and consider sequence $a_n = \underbrace{f(...f}_{n\ \ \mathrm{times}}(x))$. The hypothesis is following: $\{a_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $x$.
First it seemed unreasonable, and I tried to find counter-example. But in a series of different cases this actually worked. I've failed to find counter-example, but I have no idea how to approach the proof. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $(M,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f:M\rightarrow M$ is an isometry ($d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ for any $x,y\in M$), then $f$ is a homeomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477149/if-m-d-is-a-compact-metric-space-and-fm-rightarrow-m-is-an-isometry-dx)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, I wouldn't consider it a duplicate. I still don't quite get how these questions are connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ is compact, $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence, say $a_{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is strictly increasing.

Note that $\displaystyle ||a_{\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)}-a_{0}||=||f^{\phi(n)}(a_{\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)})-f^{\phi(n)}(a_{0})||=||a_{\phi(n+1)}-a_{\phi(n)}||\to 0$.

It's possible to choose $\phi_n$ such that  $\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)$ is increasing. $a_{\phi(n+1)-\phi(n)}$ is the subsequence you're looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the first equality. Did you assume $f$ is linear?

Comment: @bartgol $f$ is an isometry.

Comment: That tells me that $\|a-b\|=\|f(a-b)\|$, but you wrote something like $\|a-b\|=\|f(a)-f(b)\|$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @bartgol an isometry is a mapping that preserves distances, ie. $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$. Using the distance induced by a norm yields $||f(x)-f(y)||=||x-y||$.

Comment: Of course. Stupid question...