# Prove that an isometry is a bijection

Tags: group-theory

attempt of solution:

In order to show a bijection, we require two steps: 
1) show that it is injective
2) show that it is surjective

I have already proved the part to show injectivity but i am not quite sure how to show surjectivity

The idea I have is to pick a point y in the codomain of the isometry function, f,  and show that there exists a point x in the domain such that f(x) = y

I don't know how to start on this, any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of isometry? (Some consider the bijective condition to be part of the definition)

Comment: This is not true in general.  The identity map from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$ (with the usual metrics) is an isometry, but it is not a bijection.

Comment: If isometry means distance-preserving map then $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto 1+x$, is a non-bijective isometry. Something is missing in your problem (isometry of what?)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170989/a-isometric-map-in-metric-space-is-surjective and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36502/isometries-of-mathbbrn

Answer (score 3):

We will assume that surjectivity is not built into the definition. The ambient spaces have not been specified.  We will assume that $\phi$ is a distance-preserving map from $S=\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $p$ be in the target space, and let $q_1,q_2, \dots, q_{n+1}$ be points in the image of $S$ under $\phi$.

Let $d_i$ be the distance from $p$ to $q_i$. Let $b_i$ be such that $\phi(b_i)=q_i$.

Then there is a unique $a$ such that the distance from $a$ to $b_i$ is $d_i$ for all $i$. It follows that $\phi(a)=p$.

**Remark:** The assumption that the domain and codomain are each $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a strong one. But without *some* assumptions, one cannot expect to be able to prove the result, since there are straightforward counterexamples.

Comment: Is assuming a compact metric space a sufficient alternative to assuming $\Bbb R^n$, e.g. $\phi:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\sigma \in $ ENDV, ker($\sigma$)=0, since $\sigma$ is isometry.

Then with rank-nullity theory, dim(Im($\sigma$))= dim(V), i.e. Im($\sigma$) = V, now we can conclude that $\sigma$ is a bijection.