# Show that $f$ is onto

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be such that $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$. Show that f is onto. Hint: Fix $y\in X $and $ x_1\in X$, define $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$, observe that $d(x_n,x_{n+k})=d(y,x_n)$.

It is easy to show that 
\begin{align*}
 d(x_n,x_{n+k})&=d(f(x_{n-1}),f(x_{n+k-1})) \\
 &=d(x_{n-1},x_{n+k-1})\\
 &=d(x_{n-k},x_n)
\end{align*}
I don't understand how we get  $d(y,x_n)$.Why $y$ must be an element in $x_n$?

Comment: You used *compactness* tag, but forgot to mention it in the question: $X$ must be a *compact* metric space.

Comment: yeah, my bad,how does compactness make a difference?

Comment: it does... $\,\,\!$

Comment: @Berci He's not asking that facetiously, it's a serious question.

Comment: The hint still doesn’t make sense, but you can find one proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36511/12042) and another [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170999/12042). The second one may be what the hint was supposed to suggest.

Comment: @Will: Your rudeness is uncalled for, especially since it appears that the OP was given a faulty question.

Answer (score 3):

The proposition is not true as it stands: consider $X$ the right halfplane $X:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x>0\}$, and let $f$ be a shift to the right: $f((x,y)):=(x+1,y)$.

**Update:** Assuming that $X$ is compact, makes difference.

**Hint:** If a hint doesn't help, don't insist to find it out, rather look for the solution for the original problem.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention $X$ is a compact metric space, what about now?