# Group of distances

Tags: metric-spaces

How to prove that $$g:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 \in G =  \{g \, | \, \text{ for each } g \text{ exists } n\in\mathbb{Z} : r(g(x),g(y)=2^n r(x,y) \}$$ for each $x,y\in \Bbb R^3, r$ is an euclidean distance) is a bijection? Have no idea.

I have the task to prove that $G$ is a group or isn't. Here is the task : $r$ is a euclidean metric of space $L = \Bbb R^3$. Does $G$ - multiplicity of transformations of $L$ (for each $g\in G$ exist $n\in\mathbb Z : r(g(x),g(y))=2^n r(x,y)$ for each $x,y\in L$) form a group?

My teacher said that first of all it's necessary to prove if it is a bijection or not, and if it is closed or not.

Comment: Don't quite understand what is $g$ actually...?

Comment: Are you saying that $g$ satisfies the mentioned property for some $n$?

Comment: Perhaps if you edit the [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a little more, we could understand exactly what you're asking :)

Comment: @fuglede made a mistake, forget to put "exist"

Comment: @Shaun done it)

Comment: @fuglede i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Let $g \in G$. First of all, $g$ is injective, since if $g(x) = g(y)$, then
$$r(x,y) = 2^{-n}r(g(x),g(y)) = 0,$$
so $x = y$.

For surjectivity, define $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$f(x) = \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{2^n}.$$
To show that $g$ is surjective, it suffices to show that $f$ is. Now $f$ is constructed to satisfy $f(0) = 0$, and by homogeneity and translation invariance,
$$\lVert f(x) -f(y) \rVert = r(f(x),f(y)) = 2^{-n}r(g(x),g(y)) = r(x,y) = \lVert x -y\rVert,$$
and so the claim follows by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36502/isometries-of-mathbbrn/36511#36511) to a similar question.

Comment: can't understand here r(f(x),f(0)) = 2^{-n}r(g(x),g(0)) =... how do you make this...and  I don't understand why F is surjective

Comment: The first one follows from homogeneity and translation invariance, $$r(f(x),f(0)) = r(\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{2^n},\frac{g(0)-g(0)}{2^n}) = 2^{-n}r(g(x)-g(0),g(0)-g(0)) = 2^{-n}r(g(x),g(0)).$$ That $f$ is surjective is the content of the linked answer

Comment: can't understand proof of 'similar question'. don't have much knowledge in this area. Could you explain in detail why F - surjective?

Comment: The links in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170989/a-isometric-map-in-metric-space-is-surjective) give a couple of different proofs that may be useful.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to sort out

Comment: maybe you know how to prove if G closed or not?

Comment: Closed under composition, you mean?

Comment: yes, that's what i mean

Comment: If $g_1, g_2 \in G$ with corresponding integers $n_1$ and $n_2$, then $g_1 \circ g_2$ satisfies the condition defining $G$ with $n = n_1 + n_2$. This you can see by simply writing out the equation.

Comment: Your trick allows you to look at maps from each $\{x\in\Bbb R^3:\|x\|\le M\}$ to itself, which gives you compactness, but you haven’t actually shown that $f$ is an isometry, so you can’t yet apply the linked result.