# Prove that an isometry of a compact metric space is not topologically mixing.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof, isometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and let $f:X\to X$ be an isometry. We need to show that $f$ is not topologically mixing. Recall that if $Y$ is a topological space and a map $g:Y \to Y$ is continuous then $g$ is topologically mixing if for every pair of non-empty open sets $U, V \subseteq X$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{-n}(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset \, \forall n \geq n_0.$

**My attempt:** Fix an arbitrary $x \in X.$ Suppose $f$ was topologically mixing and applying the mixing condition to $U= V = B(x, \frac{1}{k})$ we can find a strictly increasing sequence $(n_{k}) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{-n}(B(x, \frac{1}{k}))\cap B(x, \frac{1}{k}) \neq \emptyset \, \forall n \geq n_k$

$\Rightarrow \, \, \exists \, (x_k) \in B(x, \frac{1}{k})$ such that $d(f^{n}(x_{k}), x) < \dfrac{1}{k}$ for $n\geq n_{k}$

By the fact that an [isometry of a compact metric space must be a homeomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170989/360587) and that $f$ is an isometry we can say:

$\Rightarrow d(x_k, x)< \dfrac{1}{k}$ and $d(x_k, f^{-n}(x))< \dfrac{1}{k}$ for $n \geq n_{k}$

$\Rightarrow d(x, f^{-n}(x))< \dfrac{2}{k}$ for $n \geq n_{k}$ (by the triangle inequality)

$\Rightarrow d(x, f^{n}(x))< \dfrac{2}{k}$ for $n \geq n_{k}$

Then taking limits as $k \to \infty$, we note that $n_{k} \to \infty$ and hence $n \to \infty.$

$\Rightarrow f^{n}(x) \to x$ so by continuity, $f^{n+1}(x)\to f(x)$ and we must therefore have $f(x)=x.$

But $x \in X$ was arbitrary. So $f$ must be the identity, but it's immediately clear that the identity cannot be mixing (take two disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X.$) and we get a contradiction.

Therefore no such $f$ can be mixing.

**My question:** Is this proof correct? If so, what might be a simpler proof perhaps avoiding use of the fact that such an $f$ is in fact invertible?

Answer (score 1):

Although it has been a long time, I think it's useful to provide an answer.

First of all, we need one more assumption that $X$ contains at least two points. Let $x \neq y \in X$. Suppose $d(x, y) = 4\delta$ then choose open balls $B(x, \delta)$ and $B(y, \delta)$ with $B(x, \delta) \cap B(y,\delta) = \emptyset$. Then consider the open ball $U$ with radius $\frac{\delta}{2}$. If $f$ is topologically mixing then we have there exist $n_x, n_y$ such that $f^n(U) \cap B(x, \delta) \neq \emptyset$ and $f^n(U) \cap B(y, \delta) \neq \emptyset$ for all $n \geq \max\{n_1, n_2\}$. However, as $f$ is an isometry, then we have \begin{align} d(x,y) &\leq d(x, f^n(z_1)) + d(f^n(z_1), f^n(z_2)) + d(f^n(z_2), y) \\
&= d(x, f^n(z_1)) + d(z_1, z_2) + d(f^n(z_2), y) \\
&\leq \delta + \delta + \delta = 3\delta \end{align} where $f^n(z_1) \in B(x, \delta)$ and $f^n(z_2) \in B(y, \delta)$.
Then it contradicts to the fact that $d(x, y) = 4\delta$. Therefore we have $f$ is not topologically mixing.