# Distance preserving map on finite dimensional normed space E is a bijection

Tags: banach-spaces, isometry

The problem is to show that for $E$ a finite dimensional normed space and $T:E\to E$ a map (not necessarilly linear) such that $\Vert T(x)-T(y)\Vert =\Vert x-y\Vert \forall x,y\in E$is a bijection.

1-1 is trivial.  Onto I'm trying to use the fact that either the sphere or ball is compact to get it, but I'm hitting a wall.   My efforts:

Since $T$ is Lipschitz, it's continuous.  Let $T(0)=x_0$ .  Then we have $\Vert T(x)-x_0 \Vert=\Vert x \Vert \forall x\in E$. Look at the unit closed ball (or sphere, not sure which is easier) around $0$.  (If it works for the unit ball, it will work equally for any other distance, and thus replacing 1 with every other number will get me the whole space).
Since E is finite dimensional, it is compact. Thus $T(B(0,1))$ is compact.  We have $\forall x\in B(0,1),\Vert x \vert \le 1$,  hence $\Vert T(x) -x_0 \Vert \le 1$,  thus $T(x)\in B(x_0,1)$, so $T(B(0,1))\subseteq B(x_0,1) $.

I want equality,  because then I'd be done, but I can't seem to get it, even though it's obvious that since it preserves distance it must be equal.  I know it's a compact subset of a compact set,   so if I had a point in one and not the other then the distance to the closed set would be positive...trying to construct a sequence then use sequential compactness hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?   My other thought seemed highly silly,  though I did try it for a bit....induction on the dimension of the space.   That got me that every point with a 0 in one of the components is hit by $T$,  but I couldn't get past that.

Comment: See the proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36511/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hmm, seems to be via the lebesgue number then?   And I'm pretty sure I can't assume wlog that T(0)=0 like he is,  or things would simplify immensely

Comment: Sure you can: $x \mapsto T(x)$ is an isometry iff $x \mapsto T(x) - T(0)$ is an isometry.

Comment: Doh!  Just wrote out the short proof of that to convince myself.  Thanks!

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: @copper.hat Doesn't matter,  it's finite dimensional, so all norms are equivalent

Comment: I realise that, but if it was the Euclidean norm, then things are a little easier.

Comment: @copper.hat The link Omnom provided finished it for me,  didn't need properties of the norm.  I was almost there with the distance to the closed set being positive, just didn't have the WLOG T(0)=0 to make it simpler, then the open cover version of compactness...I was trying sequences.