# Isometric problem using compact spaces

Tags: calculus, compactness, isometry

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a compact  subset and $f:A\rightarrow A$ an isometry (i.e , a function such that $\| f(x)-f(y)\| = \| x-y\|$ for all $ x,y \in A$).

Show that $f(A)=A$

Now, I've already shown that $f(A)\subset A$ like this:

$\forall x \in A$, $f(x) \in A$; then $f(A) \subset A$

Any hint to show that $A \subset f(A)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isometries of $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36502/isometries-of-mathbbrn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define a notion of "volume" $V_\epsilon (A)$ which is the largest number of points you can choose from $A$ such that all points are at least $\epsilon$ apart. Note by compactness, this is a finite number. If $f(A) \neq A$, then you can find a ball in $A$ that does not contain any points in $f(A)$. Use this (and the isometry) to contradict the notion of volume.

Comment: Sorry Im writing in ipad...so.        Would it last to define the notion of volume $V\_{\epsilon} (A) = {x\in A | \parallel f(x)-f(y)\parallel = \epsilon \gt 0, $\epsilon$ \in \Re positive}$

Because it is compact, in particular it is bounded,further more \epsilon is finite.

If $f(A)=A$ you can find a Ball $B_{\delta} (y) \subset A$ such that  $f(y) \notin B_{\delta} (y)$ then it happens that $\parallel f(x)-f(y)\parallel$ $\ne$ $\parallel x-y \parallel$ 

$\therefore $ it is not a isometry... Contradiction