# Transformations that preserve distance inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm just sharing something that caught my attention these days.
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283586/learning-a-linear-transformation-from-knowledge-of-the-pairwise-distance-ranking) reminded me in turn of [an older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809715/examples-of-topology-preserving-transforms), and had me thinking about what kind of transformations preserve distance comparison in Euclidean space, meaning that

$$\lVert u_1-u_2\rVert > \lVert v_1 - v_2\rVert \implies \lVert Tu_1- Tu_2\rVert > \lVert Tv_1 - Tv_2\rVert$$

for all $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$.

---

If $T$ is continuous, then we can obtain that

$$\lVert u_1-u_2\rVert = \lVert v_1 - v_2\rVert \implies \lVert Tu_1- Tu_2\rVert = \lVert Tv_1 - Tv_2\rVert$$

for all $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2$.
To that end, pick some sequence $a_n \to u_1$ with $\lVert a_n-u_2\rVert > \lVert v_1 - v_2\rVert$ and some sequence $b_n \to u_1$ with $\lVert b_n-u_2\rVert < \lVert v_1 - v_2\rVert$.
Taking limits, we find that both $\lVert Tu_1- Tu_2\rVert \geqslant \lVert Tv_1 - Tv_2\rVert$ and $\lVert Tu_1- Tu_2\rVert \leqslant \lVert Tv_1 - Tv_2\rVert$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2811637/173410) then implies that $T$ is affine.

---

Write $Tv = Av + c$ for some linear transformation $A$ and constant vector $c$ (for all $v$).
It follows that

$$\lVert u \rVert > \lVert v \rVert \implies \lVert Au \rVert > \lVert Av \rVert\tag{1}$$

$$\lVert u \rVert = \lVert v \rVert \implies \lVert Au \rVert = \lVert Av \rVert\tag{2}$$

for all $u,v$.
We can characterize $A$ as follows:
pick some $u\neq 0$ and consider

$$\tilde A = \frac{\lVert u \rVert}{\lVert Au\rVert}A.$$

This is well-defined: by $(2)$, if $A$ failed to be injective it would be identically $0$.
But this would contradict $(1)$, so $A$ must be injective and $\lVert Au\rVert > 0$.

By construction, $\lVert \tilde Au\rVert = \lVert u\rVert$.
Notice that $\tilde A$ still satisfies properties $(1)$ and $(2)$, and so $\lVert \tilde Av\rVert = \lVert v\rVert$ for all $v$ with $\lVert v \rVert = \lVert u \rVert$.
Any $w$ can be written as a scalar multiple of some such $v$, and by linearity will be such that $\lVert \tilde Aw\rVert = \lVert w\rVert$.

It follows that $\tilde A$ preserves length, and is hence orthogonal, so $A$ is the composition of some orthogonal transformation and some scaling.

---

> We conclude that whenever $T$ is continuous, we have
>
> $$Tv = \lambda Qv +c$$
>
> for some $\lambda >0$, $Q$ orthogonal and constant vector $c$.

---

Can we say something about $T$ if continuity is not presumed?

Answer (score 1):

If such $T$ is continuous at one point $u_0$ then it is continuous everywhere. To see this, take $u\in X$, $d\in X\setminus\{0\}$, $X$ normed space.

Then the property of $T$ implies
$$
0\le \|T(u+d)-T(u)\| < \|T(u_0+2d)-T(u_0)\|.
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$.
Since $T$ is continuous at $u_0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$\|T(u_0+2d)-T(u_0)\|\le \epsilon$ for $d\in B_\delta(0)$. And $T$ is continuous at $u$ for all $u$.